# insert number of images from one form into database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have numbers of image to upload to my database and i submit its value in one form..
i want to call this function to all my images to upload and insert them in my database in the same time...please i need help

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr><td>pic</td>
<td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>card </th>
<td><input type="file" name="cc" /></td></tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  />
 </form>
    <?php
        include("connect.php");
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {    
        function imgs(){
            var_dump($_FILES);
            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
              } else {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
                if (file_exists("img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                } else {
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                  "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                  echo "Stored in: " . "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }
              }
            } else {
              echo "Invalid file";
            }
            return $i="Stored in: " . "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];}


            $pic=$_FILES['file']['name'];   
                $pic=imgs($_FILES['file']['name']);
            $sql1="insert into emp values ('', 'img\/".$pic."')";
             $r1=mysql_query($sql1,$con);
            if($r1){ echo "good";} else {echo "fail";}
                $cc=imgs($_FILES['cc']['name']);
                $sql2="insert into doc values ('','img\/".$cc."')";
            $r2=mysql_query($sql2,$con);
        ?>

        ?>
```

Comment: Good old w3fools uploading handling, with the same security vulnerabilities and horrible error handling. I suggest you completely ditch this code and write it from scratch. You could hardly do WORSE than what w3fools has.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading

html and php in to data base

### body

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
File: <input type="text" name="file">
Filename: <input type="text" name="filename">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","acount","password","img");
     // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    //tip  insert $_POST  to recive $_GET
$File = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['file']);
$FileName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['filename']);
//insertin in to data base
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (file, filename)
VALUES ('$File', '$FileName')";
//chequing for erros on database
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
   {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
   echo "1 record added";

    //close database
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```